# Connecting two PCs together via External Ethernet cards (T568A or T568B?)

Tags: ethernet, cabling, layer1, cable, networking

[image: Ethernet link]

Hi,
I need some expert networking advise here.
I have to connect two different PC together via a unique ethernet path. Please see attach picture.
I however cannot go thru a switch or a hub.

**my setup requires using external USB to Ethernet converters on both sides of the PC.

My question for the experts is..
The two PCs can only ping successfully when I use a regular Ethernet cable (straight-thru, i believe its known as T568A).
I have always thought this PC to PC Ethernet link will require a T568B crossover cable instead.

This puzzled me.
Can somebody confirm this is actually indeed what it should be, and help me understand how this works?

Comment: If it works with a straight-through cable, it's hard to argue that that's wrong ;-p

Comment: It's working with your conventional straight through cable because one or both of your USB ethernet adapters are "Auto MDI". You lucked out.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X

Comment: Hi, if the USB-Ethernet adapter supports Auto MDI, then shouldn't both straightthru and crossover cable work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With modern equipment, you can use a straight-through or crossover cable. Most equipment can detect and configure a crossover in the interface, if needed.

You seem to be confused about the cabling standards. Both T568A and T568B are straight-through if you use the same standard on both ends. It is only a crossover if you use T568A on one end, and T568B on the other end.

Comment: Thanks, this is good info. Will try today if a direct PC-PC connection with straightthru works..(not via the USB-Ethernet adapter)